# ¿Cómo implementar diferentes portapapeles en un programa con dos tablas y un editor de texto?

Tags: c++, qt

Necesitaría un poco de información para arrancar con este tema.
Tengo un programa que maneja dos QTableView y un editor, basado en un QTextEdit.
Pues bien, me gustaría saber cómo se implementa un portapapeles en cada una de las tablas (al igual que el QTextEdit tiene el suyo). Entiendo que si yo uso el método estático `QApplication::clipboard();` no podré separar los datos de una tabla u otra.

He editado el título y añado:
Realmente el problema es que ni siquiera sé si esto que pregunto es correcto en cuanto al planteamiento de un portapapeles. Es decir, por un lado necesito que cada tabla almacene un tipo diferente de información, por lo que entiendo que un mismo portapapeles para las dos tablas no sería lo correcto. Pero por otro, pienso que si quiero pegar datos del programa en otra aplicación externa, no puedo andar con dos portapapeles diferentes, sino con uno sólo para toda la aplicación.
La duda es un poco teórica, no de implementación (lo que no quiere decir que mas adelante tenga dudas acerca del cómo).

Comment: "*Entiendo que si yo uso el método estático `QApplication::clipboard();` no podré separar los datos de una tabla u otra*. No entiendo a qué te refieres.

Comment: Hola @PaperBirdMaster, he editado el título y el cuerpo de la duda. Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El portapapeles no solo suele ser único por aplicación sino que además es único para todo el sistema y ello permite copiar datos del block de notas y pegarlos en tu IDE o copiar una imagen del navegador al Word (por poner algunos ejemplos).

En base a esto, Qt te está ofreciendo acceso al portapapeles del sistema, que volvemos a recordar es sólo uno.

Como bien planteas en tus dudas, disponer de un portapapeles para cada tabla sería poco práctico, ya que habría que diseñar un mecanismo que permitiese elegir, a la hora de pegar los datos copiados en otra aplicación, de qué portapapeles se quieren recuperar los datos (ahora tendrías 3: aplicación, tabla1 y tabla2) y algo similar al copiar datos de otras aplicaciones.

El portapapeles tiene un uso muy simple:

- Al cortar/copiar algo de una aplicación se almacena información en el portapapeles (que no es más que una región de memoria común accesible por todas las aplicaciones). Este proceso provoca el borrado de lo que hubiese anteriormente.
- Al pegar se recupera la información existente en el portapapeles y se transmite a la aplicación receptora, que es la que decide cómo debe tratar dicha información.

No te compliques la vida con el portapapeles y asume que solo va a ser uno... cualquier otro sistema que montes va a darte más disgustos que alegrías.

Dicho esto, donde sí que puedes (y debes) meter mano es a la hora de diseñar la interfaz de cada tabla con el portapapeles. Si los datos los estructuras correctamente podrás mover datos de dichas tablas a, por ejemplo, Excel, sin problemas (en este caso usa un tabulador para separar por columnas y el salto de linea para esparar por filas).

Comment: Hola @eferion  hasta hace unos días seguía un poco perdido. Al final lo que he hecho es implementar una copia "interna", y otra "externa", que es la que va al portapapeles. Así, cuando hago un Ctrl+C meto los nodos tal cual en una lista, los cuales será luego pegados con las particularidades que tienen. Pero a a vez, meto en el portapapeles la información en formato texto, para que pueda ser leído por aplicaciones externas.